# Registration page on xamarin

Tags: xamarin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQTNm.png)

Who knows how to do something like this, I do not know how to make a separate square in which the data registration will be located, etc. and plus how to make separate squares inside which the login, password, etc. will be located.Working with xamarin for the first time.Help please

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App1.ViewModel"
         x:Class="App1.View.LoginPage" BackgroundColor="#f0f2f5">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:LoginViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.Content>

    <Frame BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="20" WidthRequest="396" HeightRequest="430" VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Center" >
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Вход на Lockdown" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Title" Margin="0,30,0,10" />
            <Entry  Placeholder="Логин" x:Name="login" Text="{Binding Login}" />
            <Entry Placeholder="Пароль" x:Name ="password" Text="{Binding Password}"  IsPassword="True"/>
            <Label x:Name="LoginMessageLabel" Text="{Binding LoginMessage,Mode=OneWay}" IsVisible="{Binding TurnLoginMessage,Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextColor="Red"></Label>
        <Button x:Name="loginButton" Text="Вход" TextColor="White" BorderRadius="6" BackgroundColor="#1877F2" Margin="10,10,10,10"
                Command="{Binding cmdLogin}">
            
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="createAccount" Text="Создать новый аккаунт" TextColor="White" BorderRadius="6" BackgroundColor="#42B72A" Margin="10,10,10,10" Command="{Binding cmdCreateAccount}"/>
        <Label Text="Забыли пароль?" TextColor="#1877F2" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding cmdForgotPassword}"/>
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
    </Frame>


</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: is this page a modal page that floats on top of another page?  Or is it just a "normal" page with separate boxes for the different sections?

Comment: @Jason on the photo

Comment: that photo does not answer my question.  I have no idea if that is supposed to represent a dialog on top of another page or not.  If it's just a question of UI layout, you can use a `Frame` to surround a group of other elements.

Comment: @Jason It's not modal if I'm right, modal is a separate window that opens on top, let's say when you click a button.It's more like just roughly speaking a square with rounded edges on top of the usual white background with fields for login, password and buttons

Comment: please attach a screenshot to show the ACTUAL UI that your XAML produces

Comment: what is the **specific problem** you have with this layout?  It looks to me like the mockup you posted earlier.

Comment: @Jason Have you seen the photo? The problem is that the username and password are not in a separate field like yours (square)

Comment: that is because iOS and Android render their Entry controls slightly differently.  You could try to workaround this by placing each Entry in its own Frame.  There are many existing questions about how to style the Entry control

Comment: That is, on ios would be what I wanted?I have windows 11 and I do not know how to install an emulator for iOS to test

Answer (score 0):

You can try you can try [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) ,which is a cross platform plugin for Xamarin.Forms which allows you to open Xamarin.Forms pages as a popup that can be shared across iOS, Android, UWP, and macOS. Also the plugin allows you to use very simple and flexible animations for showing popup pages.

And there is a sample included in above link,you can refer to it.

For Wiki, you can check: https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/PopupPage.